# 8386 Ferrari F1 Racer convert to an RC

Tags: remote-control, customization, racers

[image: 8386 Ferrari F1 Racer covert to an RC]
Help convert 8386 Ferrari F1 Racer to an RC

Comment: It probably wouldn't be too hard to replace the steering yoke with a Power Functions Servo Motor, and the engine block with a Power Functions motor. Although battery pack and IR receiver might have to sit on top. I don't have this model myself to experiment with though.

Comment: Alexander thank you for the advice! Before I begin with the conversion, ideas and suggestions from you guys with experiences would lesser the job. I am just starting collecting some pieces available from my place. That is why I got interested more and more with lego.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for direct instructions converting this set to RC you won't probably find it here. It is just a big of a job for such a simple request.

However I could suggest placing [PF Servo motor](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=99498c01#T=C) where the steering wheel is and [PF L-motor](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=99499c01#T=C) where fake engine sits. You can probably fit smaller [PF battery box](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=87513c01#T=C) in one of the side covers with fake radiators. And [PF IR-receiver](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=58123c01#T=C) can be placed wherever it is convenient. Don't forget you need [PF remote control](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=58122c01#T=C) to drive your model. There shouldn't be a need for extra gears if motors placed in suggested places.

I can also suggest to try converting such set to RC on your own. It has plenty of space, a lot of potential to gain experience and shouldn't be a big of deal to convert. It might not look great on the first iteration, but with a bit of persistence and more practise you can make it look much better.

Comment: Alex thank you for detailed instructions. I just bought a new set of +power functions (8293) however I still don’t have the remote control piece and another motor. I wished I could upload a picture of it here in comment section, is this not possible? Again thank you!

Comment: @allan 8293 set won't be much of a help here, unfortunately. The M-motor, this set has, isn't powerful enough to move the model. There's also other bits missing required for motorization. PF elements provided in the answer are quite expensive. So the most cost efficient way of getting them is by finding used 9398 or 42030 set. These contain all the elements you need for motorization, except small PF battery box, since both sets come with a larger one. But it can be fit into model too.